# Ensure Capitalization for Double-Barrel Names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

In a Rails model, I am trying to override the setter to ensure that the `first_name` and `last_name` fields are always properly capitalized -- the use-case is for a CRM, so you'd expect to have humanized names.

Is this the best practise to ensure capitalization on the first and last names? Currently, it is failing the tests.

```
# app/models/concerns/personable.rb

def first_name=(value)
  write_attribute(:first_name, value.humanize.gsub(/\b('?[a-z])/) { $1.capitalize })
end

def last_name=(value)
  write_attribute(:last_name, value.humanize.gsub(/\b('?[a-z])/) { $1.capitalize })
end
```

```
# test/models/customer_test.rb

test "should capitalize first and last names" do
  customer = create_customer(first_name: "MARRIE-DAY", last_name: "kennedy")
  assert_equal customer.name, "Marrie-Day Kennedy"
end

test "#name returns a affixed surname" do
  customer = create_customer(first_name: "Test", last_name: "McKay")
  assert_equal "Test McKay", customer.name
end

Failure:
CustomerTest#test_#name_returns_a_affixed_surname:
Expected: "Test McKay"
Actual: "Test Mckay"
```

Comment: I would argue that you should not try to "fix" the capitalization of user names. There was, for example, Vincent van Gogh. While "van" is part of the last name it is still not capitalized. Awesome read in this context: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) (especially point 16).

Comment: One option to handle @spickermann's point may be to produce ignorable warnings instead of errors.  I.e. If there's something unusual then inform the user that it may be wrong, but leave it up to them to decide whether or not it is in fact wrong.  If taking that route; also consider how often to show this warning; i.e. if the record's going to be updated often, only warn on creation and if the name field's amended; don't warn for other updates or users will be tempted to "correct" the data just to stop getting a warning each time they perform an update.

Comment: @spickermann Well said, appreciate the new view point.

Answer (score 1):

`humanize` will turn `McKay` into `Mckay` so the last replacing logic will not applied in this case.

you could try add a mark for those capital characters before `humanize`, such as `McKay` -> `Mc|K|ay`, so that we still know where need to turn capital, as below code:

```rb
class Helper
 def self.format_name(name)
    name.gsub(/([^A-Z])\B([A-Z])/) {"#{$1}{#{$2&.capitalize}}"}
    .humanize
    .gsub(/\{([a-z])\}?/){$1.capitalize}
    .gsub(/\b([a-z])/) {$1.capitalize}
 end
end

Helper.format_name("Kennedy") # Kennedy
Helper.format_name("McKay") # McKay
Helper.format_name("MARRIE-DAY") # Marrie-Day
```

Comment: This breaks as soon as you have names like `van der Waal` which Spickermann covers pretty well in his comment. It also makes no sense why it would be a class and not a module.

Comment: @max, i know that, however you could think about other requirements (in future, not this) such as company name ... and this maybe help them (i hope), and i focus on solving the problem so i just create a convenient helper class and run on console.